# How to safely run untrusted code

Tags: linux, windows, sandbox

I would like to download/compile/run various c/c++ libraries from the net. These are mostly half-baked, obscure and/or abandoned projects, some of them from questionable sources. How can I ensure that they run in a safe "sandbox" type of environment? I mean that they don't touch filesystem/network resources. They should only return values for function calls I make to them.

Preferably a solution for both Win/Linux, but at least for Linux

Comment: Virtual Machine?

Comment: Review the code yourself, then once compiled, its actually trusted.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: possible cross site duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792764/secure-way-to-run-other-people-code-sandbox-on-my-server

Comment: subset of: http://superuser.com/questions/690553/run-user-code-safely, which also asks for efficiency to run on server

Answer (score 7):

For Linux, this is ideal workload for a container. You can do this simply using Docker (http://docker.io). This enables containers to be easily created and destroyed in a matter of seconds - far quicker than a VM.

For Windows, you are stuck using a VM as far as I know.

Comment: I am not sure, but isn't CAMEYO something similar on Windows ? http://www.cameyo.com/

Answer (score 0):

Running the software as an unprivileged user is usually enough. Unless you're using a kernel which is vulnerable to root escalation.

```
sudo adduser SandBoxGuy
sudo passwd SandBoxGuy
```

Now login as SanBoxGuy and run your software, the software will not be able to access the files of other users or do any damage outside of the SandBoxGuy user's directory.

All that assumes that your kernel is not vulnerable to root escalation.

A bigger answer can be [found here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13401/locking-down-raspbian-to-only-allow-limited-features/14712#14712). It was written with the Raspberry Pi + Xserver in mind but it more or less suits any Linux system.

Comment: That other use would still be able to read files, which might not be what the OP wants.